# SQL error when using pyspark to insert data to Mariadb

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mariadb, apache-spark-sql

I try to insert data to mariadb using pyspark and jdbc, but it seems that the pyspark doesn't generate the right SQL,my Spark version is 2.1.0, I din't have this problem util the manager of the cluster updating the Spark from 1.6.1 to 2.1.0, here is My python code

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession as SS
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SS.builder.appName("boot_count").getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.SparkContext
    l = [(str(20160101), str(1)]
    rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(day=x[0], count=x[1]))
    df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("boot_count")
    mysql_url = "jdbc:mariadb://master.cluster:3306/dbname"
    properties = {'user': 'root', 'driver': 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'}
    df.write.jdbc(url=mysql_url, table="boot_count", mode="append",
                  properties=properties)
```

Here is my error information

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:364) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"count","day") VALUES ('1','20160101')' at line 1 Query is : INSERT INTO boot_count ("count","day") VALUES ('1','20160101')
```

I use command in MariaDB to solve this problem.

```
>set global sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put backtics around column names or use the setting that allows double-quotes around column names.

Comment: Thank you, but how to change the setting of mysql/mariadb to allow double-quotes around column names

Comment: I use  `set sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES' to solve this problem

Comment: set global sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES